# Retrieve SObject using Schema SObjectType class

Tags: apex, sobject, sobjecttype

I am trying to create a dynamic class to retrieve a record for update.

I struggle with the following part of the code:

```
targetSObject = new sor.getSObjectType()(ID = sObjectID);
```

For example, if this were an account record, I would want the result to be:

```
targetSobject = new Account(ID = '0016A000003tqQfQAI')
```

Essentially what I am asking is how do I recreate the above example using the Schema class.

Also, I am curious what the community thinks about retrieving records using the new Sobject(ID = '...')

```
public with sharing class UpdateAccountGoalsFromOpp {

    Map<String, Map<Id, SObject>> sorToUpdate = new Map<String, Map<Id, SObject>>();

    public SObject getSObject(ID sObjectID)
    {
        Schema.DescribeSObjectResult sor = sObjectID.getSobjectType().getDescribe();
        String recObject = String.valueOf(sor.getName());

        if(!sorToUpdate.containsKey(recObject))
        {
            sorToUpdate.put(recObject, new Map<Id, SObject>());
        }

        SObject targetSObject = sorToUpdate.get(recObject).get(sObjectID);

        if(targetSObject == null)
        {
            targetSObject = new sor.getSObjectType()(ID = sObjectID);
            sorToUpdate.get(recObject).put(sObjectID, targetSObject);
        }

        return targetSObject;
    }
}
```

After doing research:

```
targetSObject = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(recObject).newSObject(sObjectID);
```

^ I think the above code may be the equivalent to:

```
targetSobject = new Account(ID = '0016A000003tqQfQAI')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the sObjectType object, use the newSobject method to create a new record in memory. It accepts a single optional parameter for the record Id:

```
targetSObject = new sor.getSObjectType().newSobject(sObjectID);
```

As an aside, if you already know the Id, you don't need the describe:

```
targetSObject = sObjectID.getSobjectType().newSobject(sObjectID);
```

Also, you can use an sObjectType token instead of a string to avoid a describe call entirely:

```
Map<sObjectType, Map<Id, sObject>> sorToUpdate = new Map<sObjectType, Map<Id, sObject>>();

...

sObjectType sot = sObjectID.getSobjectType();
if(!sorToUpdate.containsKey(sot)) {
  sorToUpdate.put(sot, new Map<Id, sObject>());
}
...
```

Comment: Amazing, Thank you so much! I just started learning the Schema class today and still really do not understand how to navigate the class. I am beginning to notice patterns, but I am still quite lost on this.